# How can i Mute Google's re-captcha-2.0 widget tooltip?

Tags: javascript, tooltip, recaptcha, jscript

Just setup the google's recaptcha 2.0 (no-captcha-recaptcha) (it's javascript based) & now having some tooltips on mouse-over to the captcha-widget.
From browser's source:

```
<div id="ui-tooltip-23" role="tooltip" class="ui-tooltip ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-widget-content" style="position: relative; top: -223.65625px; left: 0px; display: block; opacity: 1;">
   <div class="ui-tooltip-content">recaptcha widget</div>
</div>
```

Tried to hide via css & javascript but it's not working.
Maybe I'm missing something?
Should I try to disable all javascript-tooltips in my page?

Comment: do you solved this issue ? if you did it please share to me how you handle it

Answer (score 0):

This should work. You can use this code.

```
$("#frame")[0].setAttribute("title", "sample");
```